# Why are regex square brackets not working with "or" statement?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript to test if a user enters the word 'dev' or 'development'.

I used `/^[dev|development]$/.test( user_input );` which returned an incorrect false.

Currently I'm using `/^dev$|^development$/.test( 'developmentt' );` which returns a correct result.

But why do I get an incorrect result using the square brackets annotation?

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/korejuteyu/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Read about `[]` .They are not what you want or what you perceive

Comment: Basic RE. But if you *really* want to use square brackets and not get false negatives, use `^[dev|development]+$` instead (and you will get false positives).

Comment: @Jongware Great! but what's the difference?

Comment: Why was this down voted? Perfectly legit question..

Comment: It's the `+` that makes the difference. Please read up on basic RE -- [this quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) should mention most important bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets are not the right ones to do OR operation for words. You need to put them inside `()` separated by `|`

```
/^(dev|development)$/.test( user_input );
```

OR

```
/^dev(?:elopment)?$/.test( user_input );
```

OR function applies to each and every character present inside the character class. So this `[dev|development]` matches `d` or `e` or `v` or `|` or `d` or `e`, .....

Comment: Cool! But why is that? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: A minor clarification: the use of the OR `|` bar itself does not need parentheses. The OR bar works on the innermost group if parentheses are present (as do all other regex commands), and on the entire regex if not.